# Java - GSON nested serialisation

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

the following "issue" I have come across and would like to resolve:

Say you have the following two objects A, B like so:

```
public class A {
    public Double att1;
    public Double att2;
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues();
        builder.serializeNulls();
        
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }
}

public class B {
    
    public A var1;
    public Double var2;
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues();
        builder.serializeNulls();
        
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }
}
```

The serialisation of `B` into JSON works fine but the output will look something like this:

```
{"var1":{"att1":{"value":30.0}, "att2":{"value":50.0}...}
```

Is there a way to get rid of the extra level of nesting where the value in the nested object `A` is directly assigned to the attribute, i.e. `{"var1":{"att1":30.0, "att2":50.0}...}` ?

Comment: Your example code uses `var1` as field name but your JSON data uses `"A"`; please verify that your example code is correct and actually reproduces this problem. Also, could you please check if `Double` here refers to `java.lang.Double`? This issue looks a lot like this is actually a different `Double` class (for which Gson has no built-in adapter and therefore uses reflection).

Comment: Yes, apologies that was a typo. and it is indeed java.lang.Double

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; for me it directly prints the values (without additional `"value"`) when creating an `A` instance, storing it in a `B` and calling `B.toString()`. Can you please try the latest Gson version and verify that the exact sample code you provided really reproduces this issue? Gson has a built-in adapter for `java.lang.Double` so it should not use reflection for it, unless a custom adapter is registered (which is not done in your sample code).